# Why is gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I am having trouble dismissing my gamecenter view. It displays properly and shows the correct leaderboards but will not dismiss gamecenter and return to game when "done" button is pressed. I have the necessary gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish() function so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. Just need to be pointed in the right direction. Below is the code I am using to call gamecenter.

```
class MainMenu: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, 
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

func showLeader() {
    let viewControllerVar = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    let gKGCViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gKGCViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self as? 
    GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
    viewControllerVar?.present(gKGCViewController, animated: true, 
    completion: nil)

}
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(_ gameCenterViewController: 
     GKGameCenterViewController) {
     gameCenterViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Add `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` to your `MainMenu` class: `class MainMenu: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, 
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {`

Comment: I knew I missed something small. Thank you! That solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think `self as? GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` is nil because you didn't actually declare that you implement `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate`

Add it to the list and then remove the `as? ...` part from that line.  You don't need it when you declare it correctly.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do. Thanks for the help!